# Where can I find a reversible 1HP motor compatible with my home outlet?

Tags: electrical, electric-motor

### Project

I want to create a storage rack in my garage that can be raised and lowered to the floor. I'm not sure how to properly spec the motor for the project.

### Criteria

I've come up with the following criteria:

- Must be capable of raising 250kg 3 meters in 30 seconds.
  Energy: (250*3*9.81=7358Joules). Power: (7358Joules/30seconds = 246Watts ~= 1/3Hp)
- Must be reversible (**I would like to engage the motor with a rocker switch in the forward and reverse directions**)
- Must be compatible with home power ~110V (60hz)

### Question

Where can I find such a motor? I'm really inexperienced when it comes to AC motors and would appreciate guidance (number of phases, whether it's reversible, whether it will work with my home power).

#### Motors that I've found but I'm unsure about

- [AC motor mtr2-p50-1ab18](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/motors/ac_motors_-_general_purpose/general_purpose/mtr2-p50-1ab18) I *think* fits my criteria, but I'm worried that I can't reverse the motor because it's an AC motor.
- Here is a [catalog of motors](https://www.worldwideelectric.net/product-category/electric_motors/fractional_hp_motors/general_purpose_motors/) that appear to be suitable, but I'd like to hear other opinions.

Comment: What RPM do you want?

Comment: Good question. I just did some back of the hand calculations. Initially I thought I would change drum diameters and pulley cord length to accommodate whatever I could find. It seems that I need a much slower motor than what I've found so far. 30-90rpm would be ideal (3 meters * 2 pulleys / 0.4 circumference drum / 0.5 minute operation = 30 rpm)

Comment: The motor that powers sliding gates?

Comment: Rather than looking for "a motor" try looking for "a winch" - or else get over the motor, because your average human can provide 1/2 Hp and drive an appropriate pulley system (you can even add couterweights to make it easier.)

Comment: It should be a 3 position switch with centre off to avoid massive reverse velocity surge currents.  Winches are slow, noisy and rated for tons

Comment: A constant torque DC motor can go faster at lower peak constant current constant acceleration.  Such as a treadmill motor with acceleration and velocity control and suitable pulleys to reduce max RPM to 0.2m/s and limit acceleration by current limit with a PWM motor controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what your looking for is a hoist.  There are manual pulley versions for under $30 and electric 1/2hp and up running on 120v ac starting around $100.  They come with the switch you spoke of already.  You might check the Chinese freight stores that receive their goods at the harbor. . (Not an endorsement).   I start many of my projects there and modify as needed. Often many mods are needed just to meet intended use, but the hoists seem pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yes, that hits the mark (hehe). It saves me from having to source an appropriate drum and it has the ability to reverse direction. This is pretty much what I'm looking for.

Comment: If you do go that route,  just check that the gearbox has gear oil before you put it into use. Several folks complained they shipped without oil.